# How to preserve non-ASCII characters?

Tags: posix, locale, character-encoding

We have default POSIX locale in our server but when non-ASCII character like רקטות לגוש דן וירושלים(hebrew) uploaded in server its getting changes to **×¨×§×××ª ××××© ×× ×××¨××©×××**, How can preserve it as it is like רקטות לגוש דן וירושלים[image]

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your input. I tried setting both Frontend & Backend server to en_US.UTF-8 & the observation is still same if the characters are non-ascii its showing as xxx in Backend server logs when its triggered from Frontend service, When I tried from Postman to Backend server directly its showing the original name as it is, So tried to put a log in Frontend server as well there also the name is as it is but when the being passed to FE-->BE somehow its getting changed.

Answer (score 3):

that's not happening on the server; the displaying of characters is done locally by your terminal emulator. So you need a terminal that cleanly deals with these characters. Should pretty much be UTF-8 encoding these days, so any non-ancient, non-esoteric terminal will work. I like [alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty), but it's just one of many.

However, POSIX is not a great locale; it's basically undefined for everything but which 26 letters are "upper case" (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVZ, to be specific). You probable want a `something.UTF-8` locale, e.g. `en_US.utf-8` or `he_IL.utf-8`.

Comment: I confirm, copy/pasting hebrew string wreak avoc on mobaxterm, but works file on my gnome terminal. this sound more like a terminal setting.

Comment: No, POSIX locale is the C locale, so also with lower cases, but it is practically the lowest common denominator of all locales. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_02 and the link: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_03 so you see the lowercases which are included in POSIX locale